# Show that $P\left(\limsup\limits_{t\to\infty}\left|B_t\right|/t>c\right)\leq P\left(\sup\limits_{t\in[n,n+1]}\left|B_t\right|/n>c\;\mbox{i.o.}\right)$

Tags: inequality, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

$\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|B_{t}\right|}{t}>\frac{1}{M})\leq\mathbb{P}(\bigl\{\sup_{t\in\left[n,n+1\right]}\frac{\left|B_{t}\right|}{n}>\frac{1}{M}\bigr\}\;\mbox{i.o.})$

In this question ([Law of large numbers for Brownian Motion (Direct proof using L2-convergence)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099655/law-of-large-numbers-for-brownian-motion-direct-proof-using-l2-convergence?noredirect=1&lq=1)) in the second answer, I don't see how this inequality is true.

Indeed, it seems counter intuitive to me since the supremum of the right side is on a smaller set then that of the left side.

Comment: You might agree that it suffices to show that, for every positive $c$, $$\left\{\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|B_{t}\right|}{t}>c\right\}\subseteq\left\{\sup_{t\in\left[n,n+1\right]}\frac{\left|B_{t}\right|}{n}>c\;\mbox{infinitely often}\right\}$$ or, equivalently, that $$\left\{\sup_{t\in\left[n,n+1\right]}\frac{\left|B_{t}\right|}{n}\leqslant c\;\mbox{for every $n$ large enough}\right\}\subseteq\left\{\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|B_{t}\right|}{t}\leqslant c\right\}$$ Thus, let $\omega$ be in the set on the LHS, ...

Comment: ... there exists $N(\omega)$ such that for every $n\geqslant N(\omega)$, ... Surely you can continue and arrive at the consequence that $\omega$ belong to the set on the RHS? (One sees that the result is purely real analysis,
 with not a whiff of stochasticity in it.)

Comment: Ok thanks. Latter in the same post, $\frac{M^{4}}{n^{4}}\mathbb{E}\bigl|B_{n+1}\bigr|^{4}\asymp\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. Is there an easy way of calculating $E(X^4)$? I don't see how he gets that it behaves as $1/n^2$

Comment: If $Z$ is standard normal then $E(Z^4)=3$. This yields the estimate you cite. (One may find surprising to see someone engaged in the study of the properties of Brownian motion, the gaussian process *par excellence*, and being unaware of the values of the first moments of normal random variables...)

Comment: but in our case $B_{n+1}$ is not standard normal and as here https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_normale#Moments, $E(B_{n+1}) = 3(n+1)^4$ so this does not work...

Comment: No, $B_{n+1}$ is not standard normal but it is centered normal hence the computation in my comment is all you need to compute $E(B_{n+1}^4)$, so yes, *this does work*... (But no, $E(B_{n+1})$ is not $3(n+1)^4$.)

Comment: $B_{n+1}$ follows $N(0,n+1)$. If I follow the formula's from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments, I find that $E[\vert B_{n+1}\vert^4] = 3(n+1)^4$

Comment: Sorry but at the end of the day, you have to be much more serious about this... No, $E(B_t^4)$ is not $3t^4$. This new suggestion of yours makes slightly more sense than your previous one that $E(B_t)=3t^4$, but it is still wrong.

Comment: I don't see how what I say can be wrong. I'm just following the formula. On wikipedia it states that for a $X$ following $N(\mu,\sigma^2), E[X^4] = \mu^4 + 6\mu^2\sigma^2 + 3\sigma^4$ which in the case of $B_{t}$ gives $3t^4$

Comment: take it all back $\sigma^4 = (\sigma^2)^2 = t^2$

Comment: My stupid mistake