# A simple bound of the growth of Brownian paths from the Strong Law of Large Numbers.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I found the following claim interspersed in a text on the growth of Browinan paths.

> "By the strong law of large numbers we get that
> $$
> B(t, \omega) \le \epsilon t
> $$
> for any $\epsilon > 0$ and all $t \ge t_0(\epsilon, \omega)$."

I can see the following: given any $\epsilon>0$, pick any $t_1 > 0$, then by the strong law of large numbers we have that
$$
\frac{B(nt_1)}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \left[ B(jt_1) - B((j-1)t_1) \right] \to 0 \text{ a.s.}
$$
Thus for any particular $\omega$, chose $n_\epsilon$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{B(nt_1, \omega)}{n} - 0 \right | \le \epsilon, \text{ for } n \ge n_\epsilon.
$$
In particular
$$
B(nt_1, \omega) \le \epsilon n,  \text{ for } n \ge n_\epsilon.
$$

> But is it possible to let $t_0(\epsilon, \omega) := n_\epsilon t_1$ and conclude that
> $$
> B(t, \omega) \le \epsilon t \text{ for } t \ge t_0 \text{ ?}
> $$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099655/law-of-large-numbers-for-brownian-motion-direct-proof-using-l2-convergence