# Proving that a process is Brownian Bridge

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion, brownian-bridge

This is from Durrett's Probability : Theory and Examples , excercies 8.4.2.

> $B_t$ is brownian motion starting from $0$. Show that $X_t = (1-t)B(\frac{t}{1-t})$ is Brownian Bridge.

I managed to show that $X_t$ is Gaussian and has same mean and variance as Brownian Bridge.

However, I am stuck with how to prove $X_1 =0$. Since at $t=1$, $B(\frac{t}{1-t})$ is discontinuous, can we even define $X_1$?

Regarding time inversion of Brownian motion, I know $Y_t$ defined as below is Brownian motion
$$Y_t =
\begin{cases}
0 & t=0\\
tB(1/t) & t>0
\end{cases}$$

As in this case, can we just define $X_1 = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SLLN's For BM: [Law of large numbers for Brownian Motion (Direct proof using L2-convergence)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099655/law-of-large-numbers-for-brownian-motion-direct-proof-using-l2-convergence)

Since $(1-t)B(\frac t {1-t})= t \frac {B(s)} s$ where $s=\frac t {1-t}$ it follows that we can take $X_1=0$

Comment: Applying SLLN's for BM, I guess $X_1\rightarrow 0$ a.s. But does it mean $X_1=0$ for Brownian Bridge?

Comment: Well, $X_1$ is not defined at $t=1$ but Durett is assuming that you define $X_1$ as the limiting value at $t=1$ @Dongri

Comment: Ah,I got it!Thanks for clear explanation!