# Law of Large Numbers for a Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, law-of-large-numbers

I am self-learning introductory stochastic calculus from *A first course in Stochastic Calculus* by L.P.Arguin.

The part(c) of the below exercise problem on the time-inversion property of Brownian motion asks to derive the law of large numbers using the previously developed results. I struggled to write a proof of this.

**I would like to ask, if my upper bounds and convergence for part (c) make sense, and is technically correct and rigorous.**

I reproduce my solution to parts (a) and (b) for completeness.

> **Time Inversion.** Let $(B_{t},t\geq0)$ be a standard brownian
> motion. We consider the process:
>
> \begin{align*}
> X_{t} & =tB_{1/t}\quad\text{for }t>0
> \end{align*}
>
> *This property relates the behavior of $t$ large to the behavior
> of $t$ small.*
>
> (a) Show that $(X_{t},t>0)$ has the distribution of Brownian motion
> on $t>0$.

***Proof.***

Like $B(t)$, it is easy to show that $X(t)$ is also a Gaussian process.

Also, $\mathbb{E}[X_{s}]=0$.

Let $s<t$. We have:

\begin{align*}
Cov(X_{s},X_{t}) & =\mathbb{E}[sB(1/s)\cdot tB(1/t)]\\
 & =st\mathbb{E}[B(1/s)\cdot B(1/t)]\\
 & =st\cdot\frac{1}{t}\\
 & \quad\left\{ \because\frac{1}{t}<\frac{1}{s}\right\} \\
 & =s
\end{align*}

Consequently, $X(t)$ has the distribution of a Brownian motion.

> (b) Argue that $X(t)$ converges to $0$ as $t\to0$ in the sense
> of $L^{2}$-convergence. It is possible to show convergence almost
> surely so that $(X_{t},t\geq0)$ is really a Brownian motion for $t\geq0$.

***Solution***.

Let $(t_{n})$ be any arbitrary sequence of positive real numbers
approaching $0$ and consider the sequence of random variables $(X(t_{n}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
We have:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[X(t_{n})^{2}\right] & =\mathbb{E}\left[t_{n}^{2}B(1/t_{n})^{2}\right]\\
 & =t_{n}^{2}\mathbb{E}\left[B(1/t_{n})^{2}\right]\\
 & =t_{n}^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{t_{n}}\\
 & =t_{n}
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{align*}
\lim\mathbb{E}\left[X(t_{n})^{2}\right] & =\lim t_{n}=0
\end{align*}

Since $(t_{n})$ was an arbitrary sequence, it follows that $\lim_{t\to0}\mathbb{E}[(X(t))^{2}]=0$.

> (c) Use this property of Brownian motion to show the law of large
> numbers for Brownian motion:
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{X(t)}{t} & =0\quad\text{almost surely}
> \end{align*}

***Proof Sketch.***

Let $(t_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence such that $(t_n)\to \infty$. Thus, $\forall n \in \mathbf{N}$, $\exists t_{k_n}$, such that $t_{k_n} > n$.

Consider the sequence of random variables $X_n := X(t_n)$. Let $\epsilon$ be arbitrary. We have:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}\left(\left|\frac{X(t_n)}{t_n}\right|>\epsilon\right) &= \mathbf{P}\left[\left(\frac{X(t_n)}{t_n}\right)^4>\epsilon^4\right]\\
&= \mathbf{P}[X(t_n)^4 > t_n^4 \epsilon^4]\\
&\leq \frac{1}{t_n^4 \epsilon^4} \mathbf{E}[X(t_n)^4]\\
& \quad \left\{ \text{ Chebyshev's inequality }\right\} \\
&= \frac{1}{t_n^4 \epsilon^4} \cdot 3t_n^2 \\
& \quad \left\{ \text{ Fourth moment of a standard brownian motion }\right\} \\
&= \frac{3}{\epsilon^4} \cdot \frac{1}{t_n^2} \\
&\leq \frac{3}{\epsilon^4} \cdot \frac{1}{t_{k_n}^2} \\
&\leq \frac{3}{\epsilon^4} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} \\
\end{align*}

Since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is a convergent series, by the comparison test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}\left(\left|\frac{X(t_n)}{t_n}\right|>\epsilon\right)$ converges.

We know that, if $(\forall \epsilon>0)$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) < \infty$, then $X_n \to X$ almost surely.

Consequently, $\lim_{t_n \to \infty} \frac{X(t_n)}{t_n} = 0$ almost surely. Since, $(t_n)$ was an arbitrary sequence, $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{X(t)}{t} = 0$ almost surely.

Comment: The proof of (c) seems good to me

Comment: Wait a minute. What does proving $\frac{X_{t}}{t}$ tends to $0$ as $t\to \infty$ achieve? It just shows that $B_{1/t}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ almost surely. which is an obvious fact due to continuity of Brownian motion. @jd27 please read through the whole thing before making a comment.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron, isn't $X(t)$ itself a Brownian motion (different from the original brownian motion)? Do you think, the proof is incorrect?

Comment: @Quasar That has to be proven. The continuity at $0$ is the step which you have not shown.

Comment: @Quasar You have shown that in $L^2$ sense and hence in probability that $X(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ . That does not yield you continuity at $0$ almost surely. That is the main step of the proof and THAT is the "Strong" Law of Large Number for Brownian motion.

Comment: And at the end, proving $\frac{X(t)}{t}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ is obvious and follows directly from continuity of $B$ . That is, you are only proving that $B_{1/t}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ which is trivial from the definition(continuity) of SBM.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron in the post OP says that his goal is to prove $\lim_{t \to \infty} X(t) /t = 0$ a.s. as part (c) of the exercise. Where i assume $X(t)$ is defined as before, which is what OP did. Now if OP actually wants to prove something else then that is a different story, but then maybe the question should be edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is show that $X_{t}\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ almost surely . That would show that $\frac{B_{1/t}}{1/t}\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ almost surely which is same as showing $\frac{B_{t}}{t}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ which is the law of large numbers for brownian motion.

What you have done is show that $E(X(t)^{2})\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ which shows convergence in the $L^2$ sense and hence convergence in Probability. That is infact the Weak Law of Large Numbers. That is $\frac{B_{t}}{t}\xrightarrow{P} 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

To show almost sure convergence, you have to argue that $X(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ which cannot be done by just using the L^2 convergence by using subsequential arguments. That is a separate proof itself which is done to show that $X_{t}$ is indeed a Brownian Motion. To do that you do have to show continuity of sample paths almost surely.

For $t>0$ , continuity is clear. However, it is the proof that as $t\to 0$, you have $X(t)\to 0$ almost surely is the main step in the proof which you have not done. You have just shown convergence in $L^2$ and hence in probability which is NOT equivalent to convergence almost surely.

I am posting a proof, which I like the most from [Rene Schillings Brownian Motion](http://motapa.de/brownian_motion/index.shtml) book.

Note that $X(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ if and only if for all $n\geq 1$ , there exists $m\geq 1$ such that for all $r\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\frac{1}{m}]$ , you have $X(r)=|rB(1/r)|\to \frac{1}{n}$.

(To understand the above, recall the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity. Note that $\frac{1}{n}$ works as $\epsilon$ and $\frac{1}{m}$ works as $\delta$).

That is,
$$\{X(t)\to 0\} = \cap_{n\geq 1}\cup_{m\geq 1}\cap_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\frac{1}{m}]}\{X(r)\leq\frac{1}{n}\}$$

But the RHS will have the same probability as $\cap_{n\geq 1}\cup_{m\geq 1}\cap_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\frac{1}{m}]}\{W(t)\leq\frac{1}{n}\}$ where $W$ denotes a standard brownian motion. This is because $X_{t}$ and $W_{t}$ have the same law, i.e. the same finite dimensional distributions and the union/intersections on the RHS was all countable.

Thus $P(\{X(t)\to 0\,,t\to 0\})=P(\{W(t)\to 0\,,t\to 0\}) = 1$ and thats it.

This actually shows that $X(t)$ is a bonafide Standard Brownian Motion as we have established continuity as well.

There are many other ways of proving this. For example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099655/law-of-large-numbers-for-brownian-motion-direct-proof-using-l2-convergence) . A standard proof goes by the Doob's Maximal inequality. See [this note](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/amarsiglietti/files/Lecture_Notes_MAP_6473___Part_4.pdf)

Actually, time inversion and law of large numbers are the two sides of the same coin. One implies and is implied by the other.

Comment: Why are we happy with $\{X(r) \leq \frac{1}{n}\}$ holding only for the rationals in $(0,\frac{1}{m}]$? I understand, we want to work with countable unions/intersections. 

But, for instance, when it comes to functions like $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$, we have,  $(\forall \epsilon>0)$, $\forall r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,\frac{1}{m}]$, $|f(r)-f(0)|<\epsilon$, but $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: That is just due to the density of rational numbers and the fact that $X(t)$ is continuous for $t>0$ and for $t\geq a>0$ is a uniformly continuous function for each $a>0$ .

Comment: To elaborate further, a function defined on a dense subset such that it is uniformly continuous on all compact subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ , extends uniquely to a continuous function. That is precisely what I have done above.