# How can I show that $(tB_{1/t} \Bbb{1}_{t>0})_{t\geq 0}$ is continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Let $B$ be a Brownian motion and consider $X:=(tB_{1/t} \Bbb{1}_{t>0})_{t\geq 0}$ the so called time inversion. I want to show that the paths of $X$ are continuous for all $t\in [0,\infty)$.

First I remark that clearly $t\mapsto X_t$ is continuous for all $t>0$. Thus it remains to check right continuity at $t=0$. Remark that by definition $X_0=0$, so we need to check that $\Bbb{P}(\lim_{t\downarrow 0}X_t=0)=1 $. $$\begin{align}\Bbb{P}\left(\lim_{t\downarrow 0}X_t=0\right)&=\Bbb{P}\left(\forall \epsilon>0~\exists \delta>0:~\forall|t|<\delta \Rightarrow |X_t|<\epsilon\right)\\&=\Bbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\bigcup_{\delta>0}\bigcap_{t\in (0,\delta)}\|X_t\|<\epsilon\right)\\&=\Bbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\bigcup_{\delta>0}\bigcap_{t\in (0,\delta)}\|B_t\|<\epsilon\right)=1\end{align}$$
Does this work?

Comment: You are taking intersections and union over an(or rather $3$) uncountable families . Hence the resulting set need not even lie inside the sigma algebra which you had fixed for your probability space. Instead, you have to go to a countable union and intersection. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712088/law-of-large-numbers-for-a-brownian-motion/4712301#4712301) and also read the comments under my answer. I think that should be enough to clear your confusion

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron aha so instead of $\epsilon>0$ I take $n\in \Bbb{N}$ and instead of $\delta>0$ I take $m\in \Bbb{N}$ and then I take $t\in [0,1/m]\cap \Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes. Exactly @summerday